# How to store external IDs from different sources?

Tags: schema, rdbms

I have a table of customers with a PK that we can use as an identifier for our internal system. These customers may belong to different companies, each of which may have an external ID in some arbitrary structure to identify the customer. Furthermore, customers and companies have a many to many relationship.

My dilemma is whether I should store the external ID in the linking table itself or via some external table (because the external IDs may be of arbitrary form). We need to be able to find customers for a particular company via internal or external ID.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the `ExternalID` is in an arbitrary format should not impact the design of the schema. As it's a many to many relationship, you can use the following:

```
Customer
- ID
- Name
- etc...

CustomerCompany
- CustomerID (PK, FK to Customer)
- ExternalID 
- CompanyID (PK, FK to Company) 

Company
- ID
- Name
- etc...
```

Depending on the business logic, it may also make sense to include `ExternalID` in the primary key for the `CustomerCompany` table.

Comment: The types of external IDs may be different from company to company, though (i.e. string, int, whatever) – I guess I can just use varchar to be generic. Furthermore, this case hasn't come up yet, but what if some company uses a composite key to identify their customers. I suppose I could serialize it, but maybe it belongs in a separate table. However, then I'm at risk of needing a table of external IDs for every company.

Comment: @Rob It sounds like varchar may be the way to go if there really are no constraints to the ID contents. You don't want to be stuck adding new tables for every time a new company is added, that could get messy over time.

Answer (score 0):

@Rob As LowlyDBA mentioned the traditional linking table of CustomerCompany should be sufficient. In regards to if a composite key is needed to identify customers from one system, you can solve that a couple of ways:

1. Serialize the composite key, as you mentioned
2. Have a series of nullable VARCHAR fields (CompositeKey1, CompositeKey2, CompositeKey3, etc) and you can have a computed column that concatenates them if you want something human readable
3. If you want a more normalized table, you can have a single identifier field for the customer but don't make it the primary key of the table, instead use an alternative primary key (such as the identifier value plus a uniquely generated value for that customer), and insert a row for each identifier in the composite key. Then have a view on top of that table that JOINs all the rows of the same customer together.

Each solution has its own benefits and drawbacks.